# How to pass value from url (taken from JSP) to the controller in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a delete button in my JSP to delete rows in my DB. By clicking on the button i will get the row ID and set it in my URL like this:

```html
<tr>
 <td><c:out value="${project.projectId}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.title}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.domain}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.lang}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.author}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.created}" /></td>
 <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project/edit/${project.projectId}">Edit</a>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project/delete/${project.projectId}">Delete</a>
 </td>
```

and this is the url that i get: http://localhost:8080/IRS/project/delete/414

Now 414 is the Row ID. at this point i want to sent this ID to my controller and from there delete the row. Can someone please help me on that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So Thanks to Adnriy i fount out that my SpringDispacher in the xml file is not directing my url to the correct Controller.

Since I don't have enough knowledge about xml files I found another way to go around it, however i know its a little bit creepy but it was good for quick fix.

Here is the new HTML:

```html
<tr>
 <td><c:out value="${project.projectId}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.title}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.domain}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.lang}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.author}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${project.created}" /></td>
 <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project/${project.projectId}/edit.do">Edit</a>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project/${project.projectId}/delete.do">Delete</a>
 </td>
```

and then in my controller i used this value:

```js
@RequestMapping(value="/project/{prjId}/delete.do" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView delete(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String prjId) throws IOException{
  ......
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This url can be mapped as following in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/project/delete/{projId}")
public String deleteFunction(@PathVariable String projId){

  ...

}
```

**EDIT:**
Without having detailed information about your project, it is little bit hard to answer your question. The information that I'm talking about is: project folder structure, web.xml, application context configurations, if your configurations are xml or annotation based. If you are not very experienced in Spring MVC, I'd suggest you to:

- Carefully read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) documentation
- Take a look at [this](https://github.com/andriyboychenko/spring-proj-template-no-xml) and [this](https://github.com/andriyboychenko/spring-proj-template) spring project templates to understand Spring MVC.

Definitively your issue in the controller mapping. Verify if in your context configuration file (equivalent to `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/application-servlet.xml` from [this](https://github.com/andriyboychenko/spring-proj-template) template) you have `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

Comment: Andriy thanks for the reply. But I'm still getting "HTTP Status 404/the request resource is not available " error. I don't know how to direct my JSP to the controller.

Comment: If you are using xml based spring configurations, could you provide your context bean definition (can be found in `*-servlet.xml` file) and `servlet-mappin`, which could be found in `web.xml`?? I've also changed `@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{projId}")` to `@RequestMapping(value="/project/delete/{projId}")`

Comment: HI, this is the servlet-mapping:                                                 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>